# select statement to display desired output

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a column in table with values similar to this:

```
key_value
```

eg:

```
3933984948498934_khkhk
81299191ahgtyu092092092019_92982
abh182772hjjlj98879bjj_122778999
```

`_` is common in all the values. I need a script to copy some portion of the value i.e. copy everything before `_` and not display anything after `_`  for all the values in that column.

I need a select statement to display output as mentioned above.

eg: Actual value is `3933984948498934_khkhk` but I need just `3933984948498934`
 Actual value `81299191ahgtyu092092092019_92982` but desired output is `81299191ahgtyu092092092019`.

I feel using `substr` function is cumbersome as the values are dynamic.

Comment: SUBSTR is good, you also need to use position to find _. (I hope position is supported by Oracle, otherwise look for similar function...)

Comment: @jarhl - [INSTR](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions080.htm) *8-)

Answer (score 1):

You could use a regular expression, e.g.:

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(key_value, '^[^_]*')
  FROM mytable;
```

but regular expressions are resource-intensive; you'd be better served using `SUBSTR()` and `INSTR()`:

```
SELECT SUBSTR(key_value, 1, INSTR(key_value, '_') - 1)
  FROM mytable;
```

Note that this latter method will fail (actually, it will return `NULL`) if `key_value` does not contain an underscore `_`. So you might wrap it in `COALESCE()`:

```
SELECT COALESCE(SUBSTR(key_value, 1, INSTR(key_value, '_') - 1), key_value)
  FROM mytable;
```